# check the arguments only if the letters in that list are formed

Tags: python, string

I have three arguments and all arguments must be consist of letters like john, car, yoga.
If  arguments contain any numbers or signs I need to print error you need to use only letters.
I think I need to create a list and check the arguments only if the letters in that list are formed.
Can someone help me to do that in python?

Comment: what have you tried so far? mind sharing a working example of where you're stuck? or at least what your function looks like?

Comment: Hi Mehmet, there could be different approaches to get this solved, however in the community you would find better support if you share at least one snippet of your attempts, then we can all build up from there.

Comment: my arguments and list:                                                                      
    argument1 = sys.argv[1]
    argument2 = sys.argv[2]
    argument3 = sys.argv[3]
    letters = 'abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrsştuüvwxyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTUÜVWXYZ'

Comment: @RafaelAguilar I have to check if all the characters in the given argument are alphabets

Comment: Do not enter important data in comments. You can always [edit] your question and add your current attempt and examples. (The text [edit] here is a direct link to the [edit] page.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are expecting to return false even if it is having one string which is having numbers try this below code.

**Boolean Returning function**

```
 def isstring(*args):
        for i in range(len(args)):
            if any(char.isdigit() for char in args[i]):
                 return False
        return True

    print(isstring("nikhil","kone1ru"))
```

**String returning function**

```
def errorstring(*args):
    for i in range(len(args)):
        if any(char.isdigit() for char in args[i]):
            return args[i]
    return None

str = errorstring("nikhil", "kone1ru")
if str is None:
    print("No string contains number")
else:
    print("String with number:"+str)
```

Comment: even if it is having one string or having numbers I have to  do like this                                                                           
python3 abc.py cat dog pc4n%s
Argument pc4n%s is not a word. All arguments should be word

Comment: *args (tuple) - will take as many arguments as you give in function call. Try python3 abc.py cat dog pc4n%s. It will return False since pc4n%s is having number in it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you just want to know if a given string contains only alphabet letters (no spaces, punctuation marks, numerals, etc.), you can simply use Python's `.isalpha()` function on the string.  For example, `'john'.isalpha()` returns `True`, but `'johnny5'.isalpha()` returns `False`.  **However**, this will fail on something with Unicode letters, unless you describe your string as Unicode.  So for example, `'Köln'.isalpha()` returns `False`, but `u'Köln'.isalpha()` returns `True`.  I think this may be different in Python 3.x vs. Python 2.x, though.

I see another answer here used `isdigit()`, but this would give a pass to strings with non-alphanumeric symbols like `john+doe` or `doe,john`.

If you have a list of properly formatted strings, and you want to return "True" if and only if they're all strictly alphabetic, then this function should do what you need:

```
def check_list(mylist):
    for word in mylist:
        if not word.isalpha():
            return False
    return True
```

or an equivalent but even shorter way:

```
def check_list(mylist):
    return not False in [word.isalpha() for word in mylist]
```

Running this on a list of various strings:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

def check_list(mylist):
    return not False in [word.isalpha() for word in mylist]

mylist1 = ['Berlin', u'Köln', u'Munich']
print("My strings: %s" % mylist1)
print("All of my strings are alphabetic strings:")
print check_list(mylist1)

mylist2 = ['Berlin', u'Köln', u'Munich 2018']
print("My other strings: %s" % mylist2)
print("All of these strings are alphabetic strings:")
print check_list(mylist2)

# Output is:
#  My strings: ['Berlin', u'K\xf6ln', u'Munich']
#  All of my strings are alphabetic strings:
#  True
#  My other strings: ['Berlin', u'K\xf6ln', u'Munich 2018']
#  All of these strings are alphabetic strings:
#  False
```

The tricky part though is that you said you want your list to be `sys.arg` (or more specifically, the sublist `sys.arg[1:]`).  The challenge may be to get this into a list of proper recognizable strings, without getting annoying `UnicodeDecodeError` errors.  But once you figure that out, `.isalpha()` should work like it does here.